# jQuery and changing html output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table class called `shop_attributes`

The structure is as follows:

```
<table class="shop_attributes">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <th>Reserved</th>
      <td>
        <p>false</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <th>Show Terms And Conditions</th>
      <td>
        <p>true</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Using jQuery I'd like to change each instance of false to no and each instance of true to yes.

I have the following code which isn't there yet. Could anyone suggest the issue here.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('#tab-additional_information > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > p').val() == "true" {
            $('#tab-additional_information > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > p').replaceWith("Yes")
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: `p` tags don't return a `val()`. Use `text()` or `html()`

Comment: Also, your HTML is invalid and your have typos in your JavaScript.

Comment: To offer some advice alongside Quentin's answer, `val()` is primary used to get values from form elements (think inputs). You can read on it [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: note: you are missing a `)` at the end of your `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment: `p` tags don't return a `val()`. Use `text()` or `html()`

Also, as nobody else covered it, the `text()` (and `.html()`) functions allow you to supply a function as a parameter instead of a value. The return value of the function is used to replace the text.

That means you can reduce it to:

```
$('table.shop_attributes p').text(function() {
   if ($(this).text() == 'false') return 'no';
   if ($(this).text() == 'true') return 'yes';
});
```

or even shorter (if the only values are `true` and `false`):

```
$('table.shop_attributes p').text(function() {
   return $(this).text() == 'true' ? 'yes' : 'no';
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Paragraphs don't have values. You need `.text()`.

You may also want to set the text `.text("Yes")` instead of replacing the entire paragraph element with a text node.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is for inputs. When you are dealing with paragraphs, you want to use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to read the value. Instead of selecting each element, you can simply loop and set the text. (this assumes that there are no other paragraphs in the table)

```js
$(".shop_attributes p").each(
  function() {
    var p = $(this);
    var txt = p.text();
    var updated = txt === "true" ? "yes" : "no";
    p.text(updated);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="shop_attributes">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <th>Reserved</th>
      <td>
        <p>false</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <th>Show Terms And Conditions</th>
      <td>
        <p>true</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have pointed out, you can't use `.val()` to change the content of a paragraph element. Also, as I noted in the comments, you have typos and errors in your code. Correcting for all of that, the following works:

```js
$('table.shop_attributes p').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'false') $(this).text('no')
  if ($(this).text() == 'true') $(this).text('yes')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="shop_attributes">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <th>Reserved</th>
      <td>
        <p>false</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <th>Show Terms And Conditions</th>
      <td>
        <p>true</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```